# How to capture json data that doesnt have a key and a value

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a json string returned from MSSQL and I want to break the json and show them separately in a grid according to user inputs(from and To date)

```html
                      [17/02/2020]      [18/02/2020]    [19/02/2020]
itemseq   1 Allocated        2             6              7
itemname  2 Out Of Order     0             0              0
```

json string-

```
[
  {
    "itemseq": 1,
    "itemname": "Allocated",
    "17/02/2020": 2,
    "18/02/2020": 6,
    "19/02/2020": 7,
    "20/02/2020": 3,
    "21/02/2020": 7,
    "22/02/2020": 6,
    "23/02/2020": 2,
    "24/02/2020": 5
  },
  {
    "itemseq": 2,
    "itemname": "Out Of Order",
    "17/02/2020": 0,
    "18/02/2020": 0,
    "19/02/2020": 0,
    "20/02/2020": 0,
    "21/02/2020": 0,
    "22/02/2020": 0,
    "23/02/2020": 0,
    "24/02/2020": 0
  }]
```

This the code used to get the itemseq and itemname but i what want to know how to capture the dates and the values it contains and show them both on the grid like the(itemseq and itemname)

```
success: function (result) {

  var Item1 = JSON.parse(result.Item1)
  //(Item1=is the json returned from the DB)

  if (Item1.length == 0) {
      $('<tr><td colspan="4">No Record Found</td></tr>').appendTo($('#Tablev'));
  }
  $('#Tablev tr:not(:first)').empty();

      $('<tr>' +
      '<th ' + item.itemseq+ '</th>' +
      '<th>' + item.itemname + '</th>' +
      (need to get the Date and date values like we got the above 2 things)


      '</tr>').appendTo($('#Tablev'));
  });
```

Comment: @Kid112 bro can you elaborate more like what exactly you want like what will be your result or what you expect the result. Want result in table or just simple want to print from JSON?

Comment: @geeky Bro i need to print the dates and the value it contains like the html i attached["17/02/2020": 0,] to the specific item name

Comment: @Kid112 i am still not getting it but try filter method in the table ,Same Dates will be in a same row .What you have you to is First create a Array for your Json String like Var Z = [{.....},{.....}]; use filter like Z.filter(each => each.Key == 'Value');

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question ?

```js
var json = [{itemseq: 1,itemname: 'Allocated','17/02/2020': 2,'18/02/2020': 6,'19/02/2020': 7,'20/02/2020': 3,'21/02/2020': 7,'22/02/2020': 6,'23/02/2020': 2,'24/02/2020': 5}
,{itemseq: 2,itemname: 'Out Of Order','17/02/2020': 0,'18/02/2020': 0,'19/02/2020': 0,'20/02/2020': 0,'21/02/2020': 0,'22/02/2020': 0,'23/02/2020': 0,'24/02/2020': 0}];
var header = Object.keys(json[0]);
var data = {};
for (var y = 0; y < json.length; y++) {
    for (var x in json[y]) {
        var col = header.indexOf(x);
        if (col > -1) {
            if (header[col]) {
                if (data[x] === undefined) data[x] = [json[y][x]];
                else data[x].push(json[y][x]);
            } else {
                header[x].push([json[y][x]]);
                data[x] = [json[y][x]]; // some rows may miss here, but not in demo data => ignored !
            }
        }
    }
}
var htm = '<table><tr><th>' + header.join('</th><th>') + '</th></tr>';
y = 0;
do {
    htm += '<tr>';
    for (var x = 0; x < header.length; x++) {
        if (y < data[header[x]].length) htm += '<td>' + data[header[x]][y] + '</td>';
        else {
            y = null;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (y != null) htm += '</tr>'; else {
        htm = htm.substr(0, htm.length - 3) + '/table>';
        break;
    }
    y++;
} while (true);
document.write(htm);
document.close();
```

```css
table { border-spacing:1px; background:black;}
th { background:white; background:#E0E0E0; font:bold 12px Arial; }
td { background:white; white-space: nowrap; text-align:right; font:12px Arial; }
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
<script>
// Create and display a variable:
var car = "Fiat";
var j = [
  {
    "itemseq": 1,
    "itemname": "Allocated",
    "17/02/2020": 2,
    "18/02/2020": 6,
    "19/02/2020": 7,
    "20/02/2020": 3,
    "21/02/2020": 7,
    "22/02/2020": 6,
    "23/02/2020": 2,
    "24/02/2020": 5
  },
  {
    "itemseq": 2,
    "itemname": "Out Of Order",
    "17/02/2020": 0,
    "18/02/2020": 0,
    "19/02/2020": 0,
    "20/02/2020": 0,
    "21/02/2020": 0,
    "22/02/2020": 0,
    "23/02/2020": 0,
    "24/02/2020": 0
  }];
   var s= Object.values(j);
   console.log(s);
   for (var key in s) {
    var value = s[key];
    console.log(s[key],value)

}  

</script>
```